# Finding Point on Plane Closest to Curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, 3d

I was given the problem:

Find the point on a plane $4x+5y+z=1$ that is closest to $(23,0,0)$

I am very confused on how to approach this - any ideas?

Comment: Is this linear algebra? Can you use inner products, projections?..

Comment: No it is calculus III. Optimization in several variables

Comment: You can parametrize the plane by some function $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ and compose with the function "distance from $(1,0,0)$". The minimum will be the preimage in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of this point.

Comment: You are not supposed to change the variables of this question and ask the same question again [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2842457/557074). You got the answer which you want with the lagrange multipliers, if you have any doubt, leave a comment on below the answer for the clarification

Answer (score 2):

So you need to minimize $(x-1)^2+(y-0)^2+(z-0)^2$ subject to $6x+7y+1=z$. That should be straight forward.

One easy way is to use the constraint to solve for $z$, substitute and minimize globally over $x,y$.

Comment: Would this be with Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: You could use Lagrange multipliers or, if you don't know that approach, substitute $z=6x+7y+1 $ into the distance expression to get distance as a function of just two variables, $ x,y $. At this point you could use partial derivatives to find possible critical points and test them.

Comment: @NeilH mine is simpler than Lagrange multipliers, but you could use Lagrange mutlipliers instead

Answer (score 1):

The normal vector to the plane $$ 6x + 7y + 1 = z$$ is  $$N=<6,7,-1>$$

This normal vector is the direction vector of the line perpendicular to the plane.

The parametric equation of the line passing the point $(1,0,0)$ and perpendicular to the plane is $$ x=1+6t, y=7t, z=-t$$

The intersection of this line and the plane is at $$ 6(1+6t)+7(7t)-(-t)=1.$$

Solve for $ t$ and we get  $t = \frac {-5}{86}.$

The point of intersection is $P(1+6t,7t,-t)=(\frac {56}{86},\frac {-35}{86}, \frac {5}{86})$                  and the distance is $$d=\sqrt {36t^2+49t^2+t^2} = \sqrt {86} t =\frac {5}{\sqrt {86}} \approx0.5391 $$

Comment: i think the OP does not know anything about linear algebra, projections, etc... this is theoretically nice but to him, hardly useful

Comment: @gt6989b Thanks for your comment. I tried to avoid Linear Algebra and used only concepts from calculus. Parametric equation of line and finding the point of intersection.